# Custom error page using Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm messing around with adding a custom error page to a Spring Boot project and I was curious if I need to do anything other than just create a new `error.html` page.

I want the page to change for different messages obviously. But I noticed (on accident) that something like `<h1 th:text="#{error.status_code}">404</h1>` returns me `??error.status_code_en_US??`. Which I'm assuming is the status_code but not in a readable way or something? Is it possible to get that from just an error.html page?

Some more..

```
<p  th:text="#{error.exception}">Default Error Message</p>
<p  th:text="#{error.exception_type}">Default Error Message</p>
<p  th:text="#{error.request_uri}">Default Error Message</p>
<p  th:text="#{error.servlet_name}">Default Error Message</p>
```

Generates:

```
??error.exception_en_US??
??error.exception_type_en_US??
??error.request_uri_en_US??
??error.servlet_name_en_US??
```

Answer (score 2):

`#{}` refers to the i18n implementation and tries to resolve the given string from your message bundles. To evaluate this using the SpringEL you have to use `${}`.